# How can I restore handlers after restart and continue receive messages from CurreneX?

Tags: java, quickfix, quickfixj

I create java service for CurreneX. I use Quiqfix/j library. When i send new QuoteRequest, I get Quotes during 240 sec. But if I restart my service or reset internet connection I will stop recive Quotes. How can I continue recevive Quotes After reconnect/restart? I use options

```
PersistMessages = Y
ResetOnLogon = N
```

Mayby I not understand how work it? I need restore handlers after restart and continue receive messages from CurreneX. Or I need create myself logik and database persistence layer? Then why need to store messages in quickfix JdbcStoreFactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes when you send a QuoteRequest then you receive quotes for that request. Then consider connections from Currenex perspective. They have n clients who send quote requests. They send back responses / streams. If a client disconnects they don't know why that client disconnected or when or if the client will reconnect. It is problematic to handle re-subscriptions on their side, plus it's cleaner and less risky (say the disconnect is during a transaction) to stop open subscriptions and let the client re-subscribe. So that's what you have to do.

As for `ResetOnLogon` that's about restarting sequence numbers so you won't look for a gap fill of missed messages. Which is all about security for transactions, not for transient quotes that are stale by the time of re-subscription.

You need to handle `OnLogout` and store your current quote requests then re-subscribe to those requests `OnLogon`.

Comment: ResetOnLogon  - Can you explain more about this? I did not understand anything in the documentation. Why is it needed and how to use it?

Comment: Every FIX message has a sequence number so that messages can be tracked. Thus, if there is a disconnection then there are 2 possibilities - you ResetOnLogon which says "forget all the previous messages" or you don't, which says "here's my sequence number we need to synchronise by resending any messages that are ahead of this number" so that things are in sync - for example if there was a deal done while there was a disconnection, or a race condition.